Timer popup window no more appears after time is exhausted
When time in the running built-in timer was exhausted, the playing sound indicated it, and a window with options to stop and reset popped up.
Some time ago, this window no more pops up, only the sound continues to play (I have to switch to the timer apps and stop it there).
How to return the popup window back?
(Lenovo Tab P11 plus, Android 11)

Enable “Pop on screen” option in “Firing alarms & timers”.
To display that option, in Settings consecutively:
      Apps & notifications (1) ⇾ Clock (2) ⇾ Firing alarms & timers (3) ⇾ Pop on screen (4)
                (Numbers in parentheses correspond with numbers in following screenshots.)



Note: If you don't see the “Pop on screen” option, you have selected the “Silent” mode. Change it to the “Default” mode.
